# Why is $facebook->getUser() returning 0?

Tags: php, facebook

I have read all the other similar questions, but none are the situation that I am experiencing. I have a server side script which does:

```
$this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
        ));
$user = $this->facebook->getUser();
```

This code works fine in firefox, but in IE, $user always is 0. Why? I logged in first with firefox, if that makes a difference. Does this have something to do with cookies or sessions? If so, how do I clean that up? I tried session_destroy() and the setcookie() with a negative time but those didnt help. Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: if I reregister, then it works once meaning that I cant tell that I have registered already.

EDIT 2: Now this is happening in Firefox too....sigh. Using plugins, I can verify that a cookie is present though. (Deleting it doesnt help)

Comment: You saying you logged in with Firefox and the session isn't valid in IE??

Comment: Logged in with firefox, then out. Then tried to login on ie, but only to get the aformentioned error.

Comment: Do I need to call some specific fb logout function?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is a P3P headers issue, take a look at the following thread:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=452

to workaround iframe cross-site security in IE which blocks cookies you need to implement P3P

hope this helps

Comment: i enabled the option for "allow data sources across domains" and "navigate windows and frames across different domains" and still no luck

Comment: @chacham15: are you also using javascript SDK?

Comment: on the server side i have code which says: `if ($isLoggedInToFacebok && !isRegistered)` then include the js facebook registration code. otherwise display normal login page